# How to send 2 emails

Tags: php, oop, email, solution

I'm trying to send emails to users who are registered on my site(like newsletter).
The problem is: I have e.g. 5 users and when I am sending email to them only the first user get email and another 4 get nothing.

```
 <?php
  public function sendEmail($name,$email,$text) {
   $users = $this->_mysqli->get("user",array("TRUE"));

   $headers = 'From: '.$email."\n"; 
   $headers .= 'Date: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time())."\n";  
   foreach($users as $user) {

 $sended = mail($user["email"],'Contact from example.com',$name.' with email    address: '.$email.' has contacted you: '.$text,$headers); 

    if($sended) {
     return true;
    }
  } 
 }
?>
```

Thank you for your help
  I am using OOP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
foreach($users as $user) {

    $sended = mail(...);     
    if($sended) {
     return true;
    }
}
```

You have a loop, but you leave it at the first cycle, when it succeeded.

I think you need this:

```
 <?php
  public function sendEmail($name,$email,$text) {
   $users = $this->_mysqli->get("user",array("TRUE"));

   $headers = 'From: '.$email."\n"; 
   $headers .= 'Date: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time())."\n";  
   foreach($users as $user) {

      $sended = mail($user["email"],'Contact from example.com',$name.' with email    address: '.$email.' has contacted you: '.$text,$headers); 

      if(!$sended) {
         return false;
      }
  } 
  return true;
 }
?>
```

Comment: I noticed that you are not accepting any of the answers to any or all of the answers given to you that fixed your problem(s) (from previous questions). You need to click `the White Checkmark` next to an answer till `it turns Green`. That's how things are done around here. ;-) @ViktorR